# How To Make my Binary Translator Process Multiple Binary Numbers

Tags: applescript, binary

I'm currently building a binary translator (binary to text) in the AppleScript editor. The code I wrote only lets you input one binary number at a time. I want to enter in multiple binary numbers at a time and still have the code translate it. I've been thinking of lots of different ways to have the code translate multiple numbers (binary), but everything I try doesn't seem to work. I'm relatively new to AppleScript, and I'm pretty stumped. Here's the code:

```
set binaryString to text returned of (display dialog "Binary Goes Here:" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Translator"} default button 2 with title "Binary Translator") as string
set n8 to character 1 of binaryString
set n7 to character 2 of binaryString
set n6 to character 3 of binaryString
set n5 to character 4 of binaryString
set n4 to character 5 of binaryString
set n3 to character 6 of binaryString
set n2 to character 7 of binaryString
set n1 to character 8 of binaryString
if n8 = "0" then
    set d8 to 0
else if n8 = "1" then
    set d8 to 128
end if
if n7 = "0" then
    set d7 to 0
else if n7 = "1" then
    set d7 to 64
end if
if n6 = "0" then
    set d6 to 0
else if n6 = "1" then
    set d6 to 32
end if
if n5 = "0" then
    set d5 to 0
else if n5 = "1" then
    set d5 to 16
end if
if n4 = "0" then
    set d4 to 0
else if n4 = "1" then
    set d4 to 8
end if
if n3 = "0" then
    set d3 to 0
else if n3 = "1" then
    set d3 to 4
end if
if n2 = "0" then
    set d2 to 0
else if n2 = "1" then
    set d2 to 2
end if
if n1 = "0" then
    set d1 to 0
else if n1 = "1" then
    set d1 to 1
end if
set decimalString to (d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5 + d6 + d7 + d8)
set asciiString to (ASCII character (decimalString))
return asciiString
```

Comment: If you call out to the shell `echo "$((2#111010001))"` will convert arbitrary binary strings. I respect learning to do this in AppleScript of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script can be heavily simplified.  What it looks like you're doing is converting a binary number into base 10 (denary), and then from there into a character code.  (Side-note: It's always helpful to try and be explicit in describing what your code does--or is intending to do.)

```
set bits to every character in the text returned of ¬
    (display dialog "Binary Input:" with icon note ¬
    buttons {"Cancel", "Convert"} default button 2 ¬
    with title "Binary to Text Conversion")

set |2ⁿ| to 1 -- powers of 2, i.e. 2⁰, 2¹, 2², 2³,..., 2⁷
set d to 0    -- the base 10 value (replaces your decimalString)

repeat with bit in the reverse of the bits
    set d to d + bit * |2ⁿ|
    set |2ⁿ| to 2 * |2ⁿ|
end repeat

set char to character id d
return char
```

You wish to repeat this process multiple times to convert as many binary numbers as the user supplies.  There aren't a great many options for easily allowing multiple values to be obtained from a user.  But it looks like you're experimenting with binary/text encoding of data, and that these binary numbers likely represent 8 bits of a single byte of data, therefore it seems reasonable to let a user supply as many bytes of data he wishes in a single input dialog, simply separating each binary value by a space, e.g.

```
"1011010 11010011 01011000 ..."
```

which would represent three bytes of data in binary form that are easy to split into individual items and converted one-by-one.

To this end, it makes sense to put the chunk of code that does the base conversion inside a `handler` (function) that can be re-used again and again to perform as many conversions as one needs without having to write out identical code again and again.

Here's a draft of a script that does all of this:

```
set bytes to every word in the text returned of ¬
    (display dialog "Binary Input:" with icon note ¬
    buttons {"Cancel", "Convert"} default button 2 ¬
    with title "Binary to Text Conversion")

set chars to {} -- this will fill with each decimal conversion

repeat with bits in bytes
     -- call the handler below
    set end of chars to the decimal from bits
end repeat

-- Now convert the decimal numbers to text
return character id chars

# A handler that takes a binary number and returns its decimal
# representation.  The binary value can be passed in any of the
# following ways:
#        1. a list of characters of numbers
#             e.g. {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, or
#                  {"0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0"}  
#        2. a string, e.g. "01011010"
#        3. a number, e.g. 1011010
to decimal from binary as {list, text, integer}
    local binary

    set |2ⁿ| to 1
    set d to 0

    tell a reference to binary to if its class ≠ list then ¬
        set the contents to the characters of (it as text)

    repeat with bit in the reverse of the binary
        set d to d + bit * |2ⁿ|
        set |2ⁿ| to 2 * |2ⁿ|
    end repeat

    return d
end decimal
```